# How can I disable fancybox on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, responsive-design, fancybox

I am currently using the lightbox of fancybox to display a PDF on a website. But I would like to disable it only on mobile, so that the PDF downloads normally. Is that possible?

I already tried to remove the class with no luck:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var alterClass = function() {
    var ww = document.body.clientWidth;
    if (ww < 600) {
      $('.pdf').removeClass('lightbox-image');
    } else if (ww >= 601) {
      $('.pdf').addClass('lightbox-image');
    };
  };
  $(window).resize(function(){
    alterClass();
  });
  //Fire it when the page first loads:
  alterClass();
});
```

And I also tried it with CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.lightbox-image {
  pointer-events: none;
}
}
```

... that also did not work. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: What version are you using? If you would be using Fancybox v5, then you simply would initialize Fancybox only when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it with this code:

```
$(".lightbox-image").click( function( e ) {
    if ( window.innerWidth < 799 ) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = targetURL;
        fireClickEvent(a);
    }
})

$(".lightbox-image").fancybox( {
    margin     : 100,
    autoSize   : true,
});
```